# Error al ejecutar micro -p 5000 pictures.js

Tags: nodejs, ecmascript

Cuando ejecuto el comando: 
`micro -p 5000 pictures.js`

me sale el siguiente error…

> import { send, json } from ‘micro’ ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token import
>
> (Nota: micro": “^6.0.2”, node: v6.9.1 )

Como puedo resolver esto??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que funcione prueba con la versión micro@4.1.1.

1. Borra la versión de micro global:

   ```
   $ sudo npm uninstall -g micro
   ```
2. Instala la versión global de nuevo:

   ```
   $ sudo npm install -g micro@4.1.1
   ```
3. Borra la carpeta de node_modules del proyecto y después instala micro en el proyecto:

   ```
   $sudo npm install --save micro@4.1.1
   ```

Comment: Para transpilar micro [transpilar micro](https://github.com/floatdrop/micro/blob/master/Readme.md#transpilation)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!. Pude resolver el error.

Comment: También tienen que ver con la versión de node, probe con node v6.9.0 y funciono.